# TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderElementIterator.class

Tags: android, gradle, apache-httpcomponents

I get this error :

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderElementIterator.class

Here is my app level **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.chaitanya.livio"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}




dependencies 
{

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4') {
        exclude module: "httpmessage"
    }
    //compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2'
}
```

I tried checking all the redundant libraries but still found no duplicate classes. I am new to Android Programming and can't understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: What do you have in the libs folder? If anything?

Comment: I get this error one year later. Any update? Thanks